# Dual color JComboBox text

Tags: java, html, swing, jcombobox, renderer

In `Swing` is there any way to have two colors for single option? I mean, if I have a `option`, say `Show only cities [Alt+C]` in `JComboBox`, I want `Show only cities` text in one color and `[Alt+C]`(hotkey) in another color. Similarly, I have `JList`, Which contains a list of string items. I want to differentiate one from other by color.

In short,

1. How to design two colored `JComboBox` option.
2. How to differentiate `JList` objects with color.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YES , use html,

See this for more information ,

[How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

For your jcomboBox,

```
jComboBox.addItem("<html><font color=green>Show only cities <font color=red>[Alt+C]</font></html>");
```

will work :) cheers

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I believe that this can be done with HTML or failing that, by using a cell renderer for your combo box that allows for this such as a JEditorPane.

Comment: Read the tutorial. You where given the link in the other answer. The secion on how to use lists has more infomration about renderers.